# How can this function can be optimized to convert decimal degrees to integer degrees and decimal minutes without seconds?

Tags: excel, vba

There is the module for excel which converts decimal degrees into DD.MM.SS, but I want it to convert to DD.MM.MMM (degrees and decimal minutes)

```
Function Convert_Degree(Decimal_Deg) As Variant
    With Application
        Degrees = Int(Decimal_Deg)
        Minutes = (Decimal_Deg - Degrees) * 60
        Seconds = Format(((Minutes - Int(Minutes)) * 60), "0")
        Convert_Degree = " " & Degrees & "° " & Int(Minutes) & " ' " & Seconds + Chr(34)
    End With
End Function
```

As I am not a programmer, I don't know how to make it works
Thanks for helping =)

Comment: You don't need to be a programmer to find the line you need to adjust here IMO. Some research will come a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick?

```
Function Convert_Degree(Decimal_Deg) As Variant
    With Application
        Degrees = Int(Decimal_Deg)
        Minutes = (Decimal_Deg - Degrees) * 60
        Convert_Degree = " " & Degrees & "° " & Format(Minutes,"0.0000") & " ' "
    End With
End Function
```

Change the `"0.0000"` to include as many or as few `0`'s as you need for your precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Convert_Degree(Decimal_Deg) As String
Dim intDeg As Long
Dim decMin As Single

    intDeg = Int(Decimal_Deg)
    decMin = Decimal_Deg - intDeg
    
'    Convert_Degree = intDeg & Chr$(176) & " " & Format(decMin, "0.000") & "'"  ' D° M.MMMM'
'    Convert_Degree = intDeg & "." & Format(decMin, "00.000")   ' D.MM.MMM

    Convert_Degree = Right$("0" & intDeg, 2) & "." & Format(decMin, "00.000") ' DD.MM.MMM
End Function
```